# namedtuple field names: single string or sequence?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, namedtuple

Python allows to provide `field_names` in the declaration of a namedtuple either as a sequence of strings or as a single string with each name separated by whitespace and/or commas.

According to the official documentation, it seems that the preferred way in [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) was to provide the names as a sequence:

> field_names are a sequence of strings such as ['x', 'y'].
>   Alternatively, field_names can be a single string with each fieldname
>   separated by whitespace and/or commas, for example 'x y' or 'x, y'.

while in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) the preference changed to the single string version:

> field_names are a single string with each fieldname separated by
>   whitespace and/or commas, for example 'x y' or 'x, y'.
>   Alternatively, field_names can be a sequence of strings such as ['x', 'y'].

Is there a reason behind that?

At a first sight, I would say that the single string version is less efficient as it requires to split the input. The sequence seems also more readable to me. Which one is more efficient?

Comment: Usually namedtuple types are created once at startup, so efficiency shouldn't be thay big of an issue here. Use whatever you think is most readable.

Comment: @zstewart: then, why did they spend time rephrasing in the doc of Python 3?

Comment: Maybe they thought it was more readable or maybe it wasn't an intentional decision, I don't know. But since namedtuple is usually used as a top-level single-execution type-declaration, akin to `class`, the efficiency of this string parsing is fairly irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, providing a `str` involves a `.replace` and `.split` before mapping its contents to `str`s, [see source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l382):

```
if isinstance(field_names, str):
    field_names = field_names.replace(',', ' ').split()
field_names = list(map(str, field_names))
```

This obviously takes a bit more time than if you supplied a list. Though, this should *never* be a performance bottleneck, it is only executed during the initial call to namedtuple which generates the class; consequent calls don't have to do anything with it. In short, don't worry about performance here.

Comment: But why did they rephrase? There sould be a reason behind that. I start thinking the rephrase is due to the editor just considering more "pythonic" the single string version. Maybe because it avoids the nested construction of the list in the function call.

Comment: I can't seem to find any specific issue on the bug tracker regarding this. I doubt there was some reason (like performance) that led to it getting changed, it might just fall down to some persons personal preference (as things do on this level). @Pintun

Comment: The historical perspective is a bit surprising, Python 2.6 had the ["single string" version](http://svn.python.org/view/doctools/trunk/Doc-26/library/collections.rst?revision=56662&view=markup&pathrev=57058#l371) and then a ["minor doc clean-up"](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7be6326e09f2062315f995a18ab54baedfd0c0ff) changed the order just for Python 2.

Comment: Nice catch @wrwrwr! So it seems there was really no reason for the difference.

Comment: don't know if this actually warranted a bug report @Pintun but lets see what they say :-)

Comment: Why it's worth a bug report in my opinion? I use to code namedtuples the ['a','b'] way. I see almost everybody using the 'a b' approach, which I find less readable and efficient, I look into the doc and find controversial approach. I'd like to prevent somebody else to waste same time finding the answer. But then yes.. it's a minor problem and I won't feel sad if they don't fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

I can give one argument in favor of the `a b` approach: it hints that spaces are not allowed in the field names. The `[a,b]` way induces the reader to believe that spaces are allowed, which is not true. To make things worse, the official [namedtuple documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) does not say directly that spaces are forbidden. It only says that:

> "Any valid Python identifier may be used for a fieldname (...)".